# Android camera.open(0) returns null on galaxy s7

Tags: android

I'm trying to open my camera on samsung galaxy s7, but it always returns null.
I have my permissions in the manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">
</uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.back" android:required="true" />
```

Here is where i want to open it:

```
 int cameraId = -1;
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(camera == null){
            try{
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                params = camera.getParameters();
            }catch (RuntimeException ex){
                Log.e("Camera Error: ", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Why I always get null on Camera.open()?
The cameraId is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have a `SecurityException` since you haven't said a word about runtime permissions. The S7 has at least Android Marshmallow (API 23) which means that you have to request certain permissions (`CAMERA` is one of them) at runtime instead of only declaring it in the manifest file. Please read the [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) guide for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I just solved for myself, the answer is correct.